# Enable all Select Options up to selectedIndex

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Greeting fellow code-jugglers!

I am dealing with a kinda frustrating problem, which it seems I can't solve to 100% I want it to work.

I've got a select field with various **dynamic options amount** (*could be more than one "middle", e. g. "middle 1", "middle 2"*) deactivated and fetched and build by php. The user has to input a number to activate and pre-select the specific select option. So far it works to the point, it pre-selects the option based on the user input. But I want it to enable **every** select option **above** the pre-selection.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // PRE-SELECT TPOS BASED ON TMEMBER
    $('#inputX').change(function() {
        var member_id = $('#inputX').val();
        // FETCHED BY PHP, NO NEED TO OVERRIDE (WORKS)
 var event_id = <? echo $event_id; ?>;
 var posit_id = <? echo $posit_id; ?>;
    
        // FETCH CURRENT POSITION, MEMBER IS AT
 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'fetch_pos.php',
            data: {
                   posit_id: posit_id,
                   event_id: event_id,
                   member_id: member_id
                  },
            // GET SELECT OPTION WITH POSITION VALUE MEMBER IS AT [E. G. "START"]
            success: function(html){
                // ENABLE SELECT OPTION
                $("#selectX option[value='" + html + "']").attr("disabled", false);
                // ADD SELECTED ATTRIBUTE
                $("#selectX").val(html).setAttribute("selected", "selected");
    
                // DISABLE EVERY OPTION PAST THE RETURNED VALUE AND
                // ENABLE EVERY "PREVIOUS" OPTION
                $('select#selectX').val(html).children().attr("disabled", false).filter(':selected').nextAll().prop('disabled', true);
            }
        }); 
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="text" name="inputX" id="inputX" required="required" />
    <select name="selectX" id="selectX" required="required">
        <option selected="selected">Awaiting Input</option>
        <option disabled="disabled" value="Start">Start</option>
        <option disabled="disabled" value="Middle">Middle</option>
        <option disabled="disabled" value="Last">Last</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

**The returned value of AJAX is one of the option values, since my code needs them to be worked with and not integers as 1, 2 or 3(+).**

**For example:**
I've got the same select field but the member with id number 3 is at position goal. So "*goal*", "*middle*", and "*start*" should be enabled. If member number 3 is at position middle, I want **only** "*start*" and "*middle*" to be enabled.

Any help?

Sincerely,
montreal

**EDIT**

Because of misunderstanding: ignore the AJAX. It just returns the value as position of the member, because the option value is defined as such --> E. G. Member with ID 1 is at position "middle", hence option value="middle" and everything **before** (option value="start") should be enabled.

I just want to enable every option based on the selectIndex from the returned value selected option minus total amount of options.

Example:
3 options
returned value is "middle", hence selectIndex 1
select option with selectIndex 0 and 1 should be enabled

Comment: You can't repeat ID's in a page. They are unique by definition. Beyond that this is very confusing and hard to follow

Comment: Try to scale this down to a [mcve] using hard code data instead of ajax. Can integrate the ajax once problem is figured out

Comment: You seem to misunderstand. The Ajax and "repeat ID's" are irrelevant. I just wrote them down for completion. The problem is, that I just want to enable all options based on the (from ajax returned value, e. g "middle") selectedIndex in comparison to the total amount of options within the select tag.

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/xLq6ne7s/ Still not very clear

Comment: Yes, but the prevAll() should be enabled and everything based on selectIndex not option value (because my values are "start", etc.).

Comment: you must use prop method not use attr method for **disabled** & **selectedIndex** & **selected**

Comment: But the prevall() is starting at selected option. Again, provide a [mcve] that includes expected results

Comment: Note you don't set `selected` on the `<select>` it is a property of `<option>`. Try using `nextAll()` instead of `prevAll()` too.

Comment: Try this version https://jsfiddle.net/xLq6ne7s/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like:

```js
$('select#test')
  //set new value on select
  .val('4')
  // enable all children
  .children().prop('disabled', false)
  // starting at selected option, disable all after it
  .filter(':selected').nextAll().prop('disabled', true)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="test" size="10">
  <option value="1">item 1</option>
  <option value="2">item 2</option>
  <option value="3">item 3</option>
  <option value="4">item 4</option>
  <option value="5">item 5</option>
  <option value="6">item 6</option>
  <option value="7">item 7</option>
  <option value="8">item 8</option>
  <option value="9">item 9</option>
  <option value="10">item 10</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Simpler to work from the `:selected` than using `value` in selector

Comment: Feel free to accpet this answer if it helps

Comment: On jsfiddle it works, but with ajax it doesn't. Put the returned value (html) as value in your solution, but it didn't work. See the edited entry above

Comment: Seriously? I mean, I made more than once clear what the problem is and I also overrided the code. So please, the problem isn't hard to understand. De facto is everything UNDERSTANDABLE written in my initial post.

Comment: for the last time: success: function(html){...} returns the position (Start, Middle, Goal) and when I'm using YOUR solution with it ($('**#selectX**').val(**html**).children().prop('disabled', false).filter(':selected').nextAll().prop('disabled', true)) and not **.val('4')** it doesn't work. My option values are the positions mentioned above ..

Comment: I have showed you how it does work. Show me how it doesn't. Provide sample data and html that doesn't work. I can't guess what you have done

Comment: *sigh* Take. A. Look. At. The. Initial. Post. Of. Mine.